# SQL Server date between LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me how to insert `LIKE %` in date between. Example is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '" & startDate & "%'" AND '" & endDate & "%'"
```

So in this code where i should put `LIKE` so that data will appear?

example if i set like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 WHERE Date LIKE '" & startDate & "%'"
```

it's working..`LIKE` meant read either startdate or %..for starting it will read %

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean exactly. May you give some example of what you want to query?

Comment: If `date` is a string data type (VARCHAR/etc) then you can use `LIKE` -- otherwise you can't.

Comment: Date field in table is datetime? If so you can't use LIKE with it. You should convert it to varchar for example

Comment: What business case are you trying to solve?  I can't see a purpose for % in a between with dates unless you're having trouble with time on a date field...  I"m with mao can you give an EXAMPLE of what works and what doesn't that way we can possibly help? :D

Comment: I still can't understand what result you want to get. Please give some example with exact data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
"Select (listOfFields) 
 FROM TABLE
 where CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Your_DATE, 126) BETWEEN 'Start_date%' AND 'EndDate%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateField, 120) BETWEEN  '2010%' AND '2012%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are of type string, you can't use BETWEEN*.

If the dates are of type date or datetime, you can't use LIKE.

*Actually between might work with text because b is between a and c but it will not return correct results with date strings.

Comment: It will return correct result for datetime strings if it will be formatted yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss