# Get rows with date BETWEEN two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to return all People with birth date between 2002 and 2003 in MS-Access.

My code would be that:

```
SELECT * FROM schueler 
WHERE Geburtsdatum BETWEEN ALIKE "%2002" AND ALIKE "%2003";
```

The birth dates are formatted like this: xx.xx.xxxx

I already tried this solution: [SQL Server date between LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162006/sql-server-date-between-like)

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Solution1 :**

```
SELECT * FROM schueler 
WHERE Year([Geburtsdatum]) BETWEEN 2002 AND 2003;
```

**Solution2 :**

```
SELECT * FROM schueler 
WHERE DatePart("yyyy", [Geburtsdatum]) BETWEEN 2002 AND 2003;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But is there a solution working with LIKE too?

Comment: Why you need Like? Can you please explain the whole case/situation?

Comment: Im learning and experimenting. I just wanna know if there would be a working solution with LIKE

Comment: As @Erik von Asmuth stated, between like is not supported in Access.

Comment: You can use LIKE this way:   `WHERE Geburtsdatum LIKE "%2002" OR Geburtsdatum LIKE "%2003"`

Comment: Didnt saw his solution, im sorry, thanks to everyone for the great help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to use possible indexes, the most obvious way in Access SQL is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM schueler 
WHERE Geburtsdatum BETWEEN #2002-01-01 00:00# AND #2003-12-31 23:59#
```

The solution you referred to, uses T-SQL. That's not valid for use in Access. In Access SQL, `BETWEEN ALIKE` is not supported